# 'man airport' executable in System Library but want it to be on /usr/bin/ fir global execution (MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal.app, airport

I want the binary `airport` command which is in 
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`
to be in `/usr/bin` using `sudo cp source dest` but BSD OS prevents me from doing it. Is there a way to globally execute it (i.e move to the bin file)?

System: MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to modify /usr/bin; put it in /usr/local/bin instead. This directory doesn't exist by default, but it's in the default `PATH` so if you create it, it'll be searched for commands. Also, don't copy the binary, use a symbolic link so when an OS update changes it you'll get the new version.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport
```

Comment: Thanks. For security reasons the System wont allow you to edit the core filesystem near `/` ?

Comment: @AkashSharma Correct, it's part of System Integrity Protection ("SIP"). See [my answer to this apple.se question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379#193379).